How to free webgpu gpu mem in onnxruntime web
I use onnxruntime web with following code
/**
 *
 * @param model don't pass session but pass model path and create session in infer inner. In this way, after infer finish, it will auto free gpu mem to prevent mem overflow
 * @param inputTensor
 */
export async function infer2(model: string, inputTensor: Tensor) {
  const session = await newSession(model)
  const feeds: any = {};
  const inputNames = session.inputNames;
  feeds[inputNames[0]] = inputTensor;
  const results = await session.run(feeds);
  const tensor = results[session.outputNames[0]]
  // await session.release() // free gpu mem
  await session.release() // free gpu mem
  return tensor;
}

/**
 * Load the ONNX model and perform inference
 * @param model don't pass session but pass model path and create session in infer inner. In this way, after infer finish, it will auto free gpu mem to prevent mem overflow
 * @param {onnxruntime.Tensor} inputTensor - Input tensor
 * @param {number[]} inputShape - Input tensor shape
 * @returns {Promise<Float32Array>} - Output tensor data
 */
export const infer = async (model: string, input: Ndarray) => {
  let inputTensor = ndarrayToTensor(input)
  const outTensor = await infer2(model, inputTensor);
  let na = new Ndarray(Array.from(outTensor.data as Float32Array) as number[], outTensor.dims as number[])
  inputTensor.dispose()
  outTensor.dispose()
  return na
  // const {data: out, dims: outShape} = results[session.outputNames[0]]
  // return {out: out as Float32Array, outShape: outShape as number[]}
};

and following is my test code
  let input = await imgToNdarray(t);
  let out = await infer(model, input)
  let imgDataUrl = outToImgDataUrl(out)
  testReact(<img src={imgDataUrl}/>)

but fater infer, nvidia-smi show the gpu mem is still in use

way1: onnxruntime inference-session-impl.ts has following code
  async release(): Promise<void> {
    return this.handler.dispose();
  }

so use session.release() release gpu mem
it will retain some gpu mem and release most gpu mem, when run infer with multi times, with session.release(), it will prevent gpu mem overflow
when run multi infers, run release after each infer, the gpu mem will
way2: following will relase all gpu mem but cannot use onnxruntime again(it need refresh to make onnxruntime work again)
I find the solution: https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/#dom-gpudevice-destroy, in my case, use following ts code, it will free all gpu mem used by webgpu
  const device = ort.env.webgpu.device;
  (device as any).destroy()

